# sorting after a cfloop over a collection

Tags: forms, sorting, loops, coldfusion

So I have this code:

```
<!-- New Array for my loop -->
<cfset filesArray = ArrayNew(1)>
<!-- index for loop -->
<cfset arrayIndex = 1>

<!-- When a user attaches a file jQuery attaches a
hidden input element to the DOM with an id of 'attachedFile(index)'
and a value of the file name. This loops over the form fields looking for input with
id of 'attachedFile(something)' and sticks it into my array-->
<cfloop collection="#FORM#" item="field">
    <cfif FindNoCase('attachedFile',field) IS 1>
        <cfset filesArray[arrayIndex] = field>
        <cfoutput>#filesArray[arrayIndex]#<br></cfoutput>
        <cfset arrayIndex = arrayIndex + 1>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<!-- I use this to sort my array, it outputs YES
so I know it works right up until here -->
<cfoutput>#ArraySort(filesArray,'text','asc')#</cfoutput>

<!-- Simple loop over my array so I can output what I'm creating, but I get an error
"ATTACHEDFILE1 cannot be converted to a number' -->
<cfloop array=#filesArray# index="i">
    <cfoutput>#filesArray[i]#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I don't know where I'm trying to convert my array at index i into a number, but this is the entirety of my code. Anyone see the problem? The array should output at the end no problem, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

index in `<cfloop>` is not a number when used with array.  It's actually the element in the array.

I know, the wording doesn't make sense, but check the doc.

Comment: Ahh... *facepalm* Such an amature mistake. Coldfusion is not my wheelhouse... <cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput> fixes my problem. Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes lol

Comment: or you can change your cfloop as <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(filesArray)#" index="i"><cfoutput>#filesArray[i]#</cfoutput></cfloop>

Comment: @DG3 could anyone tell me how to get the form field value from inside the loop over the form collection? In the fifth line of code, where I set the array = to field, it is the field name. I need the field value but form.field doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffFabiny the scopes are structures `<cfloop collection ="#FORM#" item = "field">`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71a6.html